Find out who is updating my package.json file
About 10 days ago I started facing a new issue while maintaining a vuejs 2 webapp: A dependency containing the project name and the "file:" value shows up in my package.json's dependency list. It breaks my npm operations. Sometimes I'm able to manually delete the dependency, save the file and move on, but sometimes this dependency just shows up again in file, almost right after the save operation. Here's the odd dependency showing up:

I got like a good number of extensions in vscode, but none installed for less than 100 days. Is anyone else facing this sort of issue?
----- edit
This is user settings.json:
{
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_241",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-11",
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.8"
    }
  ],
  "java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.8",
  "http.proxySupport": "on",
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
  // "win-ca.inject": "append",
  "rsp-ui.enableStartServerOnActivation": [
    {
      "id": "redhat.vscode-server-connector",
      "name": "Red Hat RSP Server",
      "startOnActivation": true
    }
  ],
  "maven.executable.path": "C:\\DTools\\mvn\\bin\\mvn",
  "maven.executable.preferMavenWrapper": false,
  "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
  "java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
  "java.project.importOnFirstTimeStartup": "automatic",
  "java.maven.downloadSources": true,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
  "mssql.connections": [
    {
      "server": "{{put-server-name-here}}",
      "database": "{{put-database-name-here}}",
      "user": "{{put-username-here}}",
      "password": ""
    }
  ],
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  },
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "git.mergeEditor": false,
  "window.commandCenter": true,
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "win-ca.inject": "append",
  "editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false,
  "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
  "vue.server.hybridMode": true
}

Now a list of installed extensions. Many are disabled tho:
(treated output for code --list-extensions | % { "code --install-extension $_" } )
dineug.vuerd-vscode
dotjoshjohnson.xml
eamodio.gitlens
equimper.react-native-react-redux   
esbenp.prettier-vscode
fantasytyx.tortoise-svn
github.copilot
github.copilot-chat
gruntfuggly.todo-tree
hediet.vscode-drawio
johnstoncode.svn-scm
leosj29.primefaces-intellisense     
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-ceintl.vscode-language-pack-pt-br
ms-dotnettools.csdevkit
ms-dotnettools.csharp
ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime
ms-dotnettools.vscodeintellicode-csharp
ms-mssql.data-workspace-vscode
ms-mssql.mssql
ms-mssql.sql-database-projects-vscode
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
msjsdiag.vscode-react-native
octref.vetur
rangav.vscode-thunder-client
redhat.fabric8-analytics
redhat.java
redhat.vscode-commons
redhat.vscode-rsp-ui
redhat.vscode-server-connector
sohibe.java-generate-setters-getters
ukoloff.win-ca
visualstudioexptteam.intellicode-api-usage-examples
visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode
vscjava.vscode-gradle
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
vue.volar

Workspace settings.json is empty, do you guys want to see default settings.json ?

it's specific to your IDE in some way.  post your settings json, and maybe your extension list.

Might be some kind of npm link or alike. Isn't this you're company's homemade project or alike?

I'll post settings and extensions in few hours, thanks :).

Project belongs to corporate but I've created it from scratch, it runs since 2021. We didn't add any sort of complex scripts, it's a simple vue2 spa

Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.

Extension bisect  resolved my problem!
Ran it in my environment and after few iterations I found out that fabric8-analytics-vscode-extension was writing that stuff in my package.json file. I use the IDE for maintaining some java projects and that's the reason why I have about a dozen different redhat extensions running. For now this one will be disabled. I filled a bug report here
